# Changing text value inside of a tag in HTML with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to change text inside of HTML code with Jquery.

```
<li class="dropdown">
        <a **id="user_name"**  href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            Profile
            <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="{{ url_for('site.admin_profile') }}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{ url_for('site.logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  $('#user_name').text("Heyy")
```

my code it looks like this

[image: If I do my code it looks like this]

However, I need this style

[image: Important style]

Comment: `$('#user_name').text("Heyy")` you need wrap this with `<script></script>`

Comment: this script file located a different file it works fine.My focus is changing a tag text .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$('#user_name').text("Heyy")` beside the text you're also replacing the `i` and `b` elements. What you could do is to wrap the text into a `span`  and use `$('#user_name span').text("Heyy")` to replace it.
Here is an example:

```js
$("#user_name span.txt").text("Heyy");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 


 <a id="user_name"  href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <span class="txt">Profile</span>
    <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.text('xxx')` will replace everything inside that element, you could also use `.html('<i class="fa fa-user"></i> Heyyyy<b class="caret"></b></a>')` to replace the HTML.

#### Option 1 use `.text()`:

1.wrap your text with a span `<span>Profile</span>`

2.then target it with `$('#user_name span').text('heyyyy');`

```js
$('#user_name span').text('heyyyy');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<li class="dropdown">
  <a id="user_name" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>Profile</span>
    <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="{{ url_for('site.admin_profile') }}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li>
      <a href="{{ url_for('site.logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

#### Option 2 (use `.html()`):

```js
$('#user_name').html('<i class="fa fa-user"></i> Heyyy<b class="caret"></b></a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a id="user_name" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Profile
    <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="{{ url_for('site.admin_profile') }}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li>
      <a href="{{ url_for('site.logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the profile inside a `span` and give it an id of `user_name`

```
<span id="user_name">Profile</span>
```

```js
 $('#user_name').text("Heyy")
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        <span id="user_name">Profile</span>
        <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="{{ url_for('site.admin_profile') }}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ url_for('site.logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: $("#user_name span.txt").text("Heyy"); using this one is correct